# Send/Receive audio arrays between Java-Android and JNI

Tags: android, c++, audio, java-native-interface, recording

I am new in the Android programming world and I have already made a full search on the Internet about the JNI implementation in Android. By the way, there are lots of ways to do it, and I don't find too much documentation about DSP in C/C++ for Android.

I have already got the audio data from a recording (PCM to float), and I would like to send the data to a C/C++ function to process this data. After the transformation I would like to return the array to the Java activity to playback the result. Is there any simple example or documentation about sending and receiving arrays with the JNI?

I am using Windows 7, Eclipse and Cygwin.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Strings and arrays in JNI are covered here: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jnistring.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be quite simple,

To transfer a byteArray from Java to C++ you can consider the following example :

Step 1: in the java class which will call the native method declare the method (in my example a simple zip)

```
private native byte[] jniZipString(byte[] unpackedData, int datasize);
```

Step 2: in c++ generate the header and implementation using javah.exe
[note] call javah from the bin/classes foler (since your coding for android

```
javah -jni com.example.JavaClassWithNativeMethods
```

Step 3: in C++ receive the byte array and covert to C++ bytearray

```
jbyte* tempPointer = env->GetByteArrayElements(jInput, 0);
const char* cinput = (const char*) tempPointer;
int dataSize = (int)env->GetArrayLength(jInput)
```

Step 4: in process your data

```
whatever you do to process the bytearray
```

Step 5: return the resulting byte array to java

```
jbyteArray result = (env)->NewByteArray(newDataSize);
(env)->SetByteArrayRegion(result, 0, newDataSize, (jbyte *) processedCharArray); 
return result;
```

Comment: What if one wants something else than a byte array, like floats or shorts?

Comment: You absolutely can. You can get more info here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html

Btw this answer was posted 10 years ago :)